# Visualising 3d clusters

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, data-visualization

So I have 3 clusters I would like to visualise on a 3d Graph. I am not sure how I can add a third axis.

```
X = np.array(X)
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 0, 0], X[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'red', label = 'Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 1, 0], X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'blue', label = 'Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 2, 0], X[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Cluster 3')
plt.xlabel("Recency")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1],s = 300, c = 'yellow', label = 'Centroids')
plt.show()
```

This is what I did but I know this is only for 2d. The y_kmeans contains the cluster corresponding the row number in my X dataset. The X dataset has 3 columns.
I was wondering if someone could guide me on how I could do this?
UPDATE: 
was able to make it work with help from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feel free to adapt for your need

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import random


fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x_vals = np.random.rand(1000)
y_vals = np.random.rand(1000)
z_vals = np.random.rand(1000)



ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals, color='red')
ax.scatter(x_vals+0.2, y_vals-0.8, z_vals, color='blue')
pyplot.show()
```

output:

[image]